# JS Steam Bot Error

Tags: javascript, mysql, web, steam

Im having an error with my csgo trade bot for my site. I have the sql database and everything else setup but the whenever i try to send it a trade offer i get this error: http://imgur.com/oELLjcr
Querys return a value of 10.

I do realize it says the error right on the screen but I cannot figure it out, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Code: http://pastebin.com/sdr0Z2Ss

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, include the error message (not a  *picture* of the error message), and the code  (including some indication as to which line number matches the error), *in the question*. Otherwise this will soon be closed for lack of an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, that you doesn't have established connection to your MySQL database correctly.